# PHP native way to convert SplDoublyLinkedList to JSON

Tags: php, json, serialization, spl

I have a collection of items in PHP, and I need to pass this collection to a Java application through a [json](/questions/tagged/json) encoded file.

Is there a native (standard library or whatever) way to convert a [`SplDoublyLinkedList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php) to a `JSON`-string? Peeking the official documentation, `Spl` has a [`SplDoublyLinkedList::serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/spldoublylinkedlist.serialize.php) method, but not a `JSON` econding one.

So I was thinking to build a JSON string myself iterating through the object. I don't know if this is a bad or a good way to solve my problem.

Comment: do you control both the creator and consumer of this json?

Comment: @MarshallTigerus yes. i'm building both of them

Comment: Then it really doesn't matter how you do it, since you control both sides of the communication.  The way I would do it is create a list of objects in JSON, and when you deserialize handle the linking of these objects into a linked list (on the assumption that the order is the same as the linking)

Comment: You can also give each element a unique identifier of some sort and provide the elements that link to it a field that contains that identifier.

Comment: added tags and references to the body of the question